# Weird backslash substitution in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, backslash

I don't understand this Ruby code:

```
>> puts '\\ <- single backslash'
# \ <- single backslash

>> puts '\\ <- 2x a, because 2 backslashes get replaced'.sub(/\\/, 'aa')
# aa <- 2x a, because two backslashes get replaced
```

so far, all as expected. but if we search for 1 with `/\\/`, and replace with 2, encoded by `'\\\\'`, why do we get this:

```
>> puts '\\ <- only 1 ... replace 1 with 2'.sub(/\\/, '\\\\')
# \ <- only 1 backslash, even though we replace 1 with 2
```

and then, when we encode 3 with `'\\\\\\'`, we only get 2:

```
>> puts '\\ <- only 2 ... 1 with 3'.sub(/\\/, '\\\\\\')
# \\ <- 2 backslashes, even though we replace 1 with 3
```

anyone able to understand why a backslash gets swallowed in the replacement string? this happens on 1.8 and 1.9.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is an issue because backslash (\) serves as an escape character for Regexps and Strings. You could do use the special variable \& to reduce the number backslashes in the gsub replacement string.

```
foo.gsub(/\\/,'\&\&\&') #for some string foo replace each \ with \\\
```

EDIT: I should mention that the value of \& is from a Regexp match, in this case a single backslash.

Also, I thought that there was a special way to create a string that disabled the escape character, but apparently not. None of these will produce two slashes:

```
puts "\\"
puts '\\'
puts %q{\\}
puts %Q{\\}
puts """\\"""
puts '''\\'''
puts <<EOF
\\
EOF
```

Comment: hmmm, interesting approach. a bit less 'pure', since if you have a more complex search it won't work. but definitely fewer characters...

Answer (score 80):

### Quick Answer

If you want to sidestep all this confusion, **use the much less confusing block syntax**. Here is an example that replaces each backslash with 2 backslashes:

```
"some\\path".gsub('\\') { '\\\\' }
```

---

### Gruesome Details

The problem is that when using `sub` (and `gsub`), without a block, ruby interprets **special character sequences** in the replacement parameter. Unfortunately, `sub` uses the backslash as the escape character for these:

```
\& (the entire regex)
\+ (the last group)
\` (pre-match string)
\' (post-match string)
\0 (same as \&)
\1 (first captured group)
\2 (second captured group)
\\ (a backslash)
```

Like any escaping, this creates an obvious problem. If you want include the literal value of one of the above sequences (e.g. `\1`) in the output string you have to escape it. So, to get `Hello \1`, you need the replacement string to be `Hello \\1`. And to represent this as a string literal in Ruby, you have to escape those backslashes again like this: `"Hello \\\\1"`

So, there are **two different escaping passes**. The first one takes the string literal and creates the internal string value. The second takes that internal string value and replaces the sequences above with the matching data.

If a backslash is not followed by a character that matches one of the above sequences, then the backslash (and character that follows) will pass through unaltered. This is also affects a backslash at the end of the string -- it will pass through unaltered. It's easiest to see this logic in the rubinius code; just look for the `to_sub_replacement` method in the [String class](https://github.com/evanphx/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/string.rb).

Here are **some examples** of how `String#sub` is parsing the replacement string:

- **1 backslash** `\` (which has a string literal of `"\\"`)

  Passes through unaltered because the backslash is at the end of the string and has no characters after it.

  *Result:* `\`
- **2 backslashes** `\\` (which have a string literal of `"\\\\"`)

  The pair of backslashes match the escaped backslash sequence (see `\\` above) and gets converted into a single backslash.

  *Result:* `\`
- **3 backslashes** `\\\` (which have a string literal of `"\\\\\\"`)

  The first two backslashes match the `\\` sequence and get converted to a single backslash. Then the final backslash is at the end of the string so it passes through unaltered.

  *Result:* `\\`
- **4 backslashes** `\\\\` (which have a string literal of `"\\\\\\\\"`)

  Two pairs of backslashes each match the `\\` sequence and get converted to a single backslash.

  *Result:* `\\`
- **2 backslashes with character in the middle** `\a\` (which have a string literal of `"\\a\\"`)

  The `\a` does not match any of the escape sequences so it is allowed to pass through unaltered. The trailing backslash is also allowed through.

  *Result:* `\a\`

  *Note:* The same result could be obtained from: `\\a\\` (with the literal string: `"\\\\a\\\\"`)

In hindsight, this could have been less confusing if `String#sub` had used a different escape character. Then there wouldn't be the need to double escape all the backslashes.

Comment: For Captured group i could only match at most 9 groups and there after i am getting a match of group 1 followed by 0 & 1 etc... E.g. Consider  group one match is "<div" and group 10 is "data-loading" and the result i am getting is "<div0" (result of first match followed by 0)

Comment: It's a pity that this information is not included at all in Ruby documentation (e.g. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub). It should.

Comment: @Peter This should be the selected answer. Also, mind blown.

Answer (score 4):

argh, right after I typed all this out, I realised that `\` is used to refer to groups in the replacement string. I guess this means that you need a literal `\\` in the replacement string to get one replaced `\`. To get a literal `\\` you need four `\`s, so to replace one with two you actually need eight(!).

```
# Double every occurrence of \. There's eight backslashes on the right there!
>> puts '\\'.sub(/\\/, '\\\\\\\\')
```

anything I'm missing? any more efficient ways?

Comment: I think you are correct. But Welch's way seems better for me.

Answer (score 4):

Clearing up a little confusion on the author's second line of code.

You said:

```
>> puts '\\ <- 2x a, because 2 backslashes get replaced'.sub(/\\/, 'aa')
# aa <- 2x a, because two backslashes get replaced
```

2 backslashes aren't getting replaced here. You're replacing **1 escaped** backslash with two a's ('aa'). That is, if you used `.sub(/\\/, 'a')`, you would only see one 'a'

```
'\\'.sub(/\\/, 'anything') #=> anything
```

Comment: sorry, absolutely right. that was more of a typo then a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

the pickaxe book mentions this exact problem, actually. here's another alternative (from page 130 of the latest edition)

```
str = 'a\b\c'               # => "a\b\c"
str.gsub(/\\/) { '\\\\' }   # => "a\\b\\c"
```

Comment: Good catch, god level of documentation