# Replace "&" to "\&" in Ruby seems impossible?

Tags: ruby, string, replace, escaping

I want to replace all `&` characters into `\&` with `String.gsub` (or a other method). I've tried several combinations and read [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542214/weird-backslash-substitution-in-ruby), but nothing is gonna work.

```
  "asdf & asdf".gsub("&", "\\\&") => "asdf & asdf"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your linked question provides a solution - use the block form of `gsub`:

```
irb(main):009:0> puts "asdf & asdf".gsub("&"){'\&'}
asdf \& asdf
```

Comment: Indeed, because the replacement string is `'` delimited. Try `puts "asdf ' asdf".gsub("'"){"\\'"}`

Answer (score 2):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :008 > puts "asdf & asdf".gsub(/&/, '\\\&')
asdf \& asdf
```

Comment: It's not a mess. without `puts`, you are getting `result.inspect`, for a string, it gives you the string as you would have to type it with double quotes to obtain `result`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that you're using 1.8. In 1.8, `irb` says this:

```
>> "asdf & asdf".gsub("&", "\\\&")
=> "asdf & asdf"
>> puts "asdf & asdf".gsub("&", "\\\&")
asdf & asdf
```

And that matches what you're seeing. But, if you add yet another backslash, you get what you're after:

```
>> puts "asdf & asdf".gsub("&", '\\\\&')
asdf \& asdf
```

The quadruple backslash approach produces the same singly-escaped ampersand for me in both 1.9.2 and 1.8.7 so turn it up to four (not eleven, just four will do).