# How to replace single quote to backslash in ruby?

Tags: ruby, sql-injection

In order to prevent sql injection, I did this:

```
string = "105;' DROP TABLE Suppliers"
new_string = string.gsub("'", %q(\'))
p new_string
=> "105; DROP TABLE Suppliers DROP TABLE Suppliers"
```

Here why output `DROP TABLE Suppliers` twice?

Comment: This is basically the same as [**Replace “&” to “\&” in Ruby seems impossible?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6569359/479863), no? The answers will at least be the same.

Comment: Why don’t you use parameterized queries as supported by prepared statements?

Comment: @Gumbo Because I can't use any parameterized method due to my special project.

Comment: @scho: What database/driver are you using? There may be a way to invoke its escaping capabilities without using parameters.

Comment: @mwp Google BigQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is interpreting the `\'` as a backreference to the post-match string($').  So, you are replacing the quote with everything after the quote:

```
<space>DROP TABLE Suppliers
     V
"105;' DROP TABLE Suppliers"
```

Here it is with a backreference to the pre-match variable($`):

```
string = "105;' DROP TABLE Suppliers"
new_string = string.gsub("'", %q(\`))
p new_string

--output:--
"105;105; DROP TABLE Suppliers"
```

I can't find any documentation for backreferences to ruby's global variables, so congratulations you are a ruby pioneer.

Comment: Thank you. I just want to replace `'` to `\'` in the string which user may input. Isn't that right? Then how to do it do you think?

Comment: Adding slash? Not backslash?

Comment: @scho, *back* slashes.

Comment: Yes. To prevent sql injection. I think it is safe: `105;\' DROP TABLE Suppliers`.

Comment: @scho: No, why would you think that SQL used a backslash to escape a single quote? Doubling the quote is more common I'd think. Anyway, you're going about this all wrong, trying to manually escape strings to prevent SQL injection is a fool's game. Use placeholders or the database driver's quoting methods.

Comment: @scho, Did you figure out the right number of slashes?  The reason it's tricky is because first ruby evaluates the String, processing the escape sequences.  Then ruby sends the String to the regex engine, and the regex engine then evaluates the String again, processing the escape sequences it sees.

Comment: Thank you. I should find a way to deal with it.

Comment: @scho, I can tell you how many slashes you need, but it's simple to just add one slash at a time to your original code until it produces the result you want.

Comment: `string.gsub("'", %q(\\\'))` outputs `"105;\\' DROP TABLE Suppliers"`. But not work in my real program.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is it turns out you don't have to do that.  For more in depth info read the comments bellow.  To escape a single quote, you add another single quote.  So the winner is:

```
string.gsub(/'/, "''")
```

Comment: `%q(\')` and `"\\'"` are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I'm not sure what your point is since my point was the block substitution was still working, but I guess you may just mean one can do string.gsub(/'/){ %q(\') }

Comment: Nope.  I missed the block in your code.  And normally in a block you would just use the globals $` and $' to refer to the pre-match and post-match, and $1, $2, etc. for the parenthesized groups.  However, the gsub() docs do have a different description for the block form, and backreferences aren't mentioned in the block form--and in fact my tests show that backreferences don't work in the block form.  In my opinion, what the op posted about cannot be a bug.  The regex engine has to look for \1, \2, etc. in a String, and someone obviously wrote code to additionally look for the backreference \'

Comment: Interesting.  Surprised I never saw this before.  Never knew about the backreference \'.  Learn something new every day :), thanks. I guess I got so used to Rails handling the string sanitation that I never saw this case.  Even though we did it often back in my JAVA days oh so many years ago, I guess it's been a long time since I did sql sanitation thanks to Rails.  Speaking of, I looked up how the sanitize_sql_array does it and it leads to the following line: s.gsub(/\\/, '\&\&').gsub(/'/, "''") for escaping escaping any ' (single quote) and \ (backslash).  So \' is not needed after all :)

Comment: *Learn something new every day.*  Yep.  There's no documentation that I could find that mentions that you can backreference the global match variables.  But it makes some sense that if  $1 is the global match variable for the first parenthesized group, and you can backreference that with \1, then you can also backreference the post-match variable, $', with \'.