# Ruby /& in a String

Tags: ruby, escaping

I need to include /& in a ZPL string to break up a long line on a label.

There is a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569359/replace-to-in-ruby-seems-impossible) that suggests a lot of methods but does not seem to answer my question:

Here is my problem:

```
>>"asdf & asdf".gsub("&", "\\\\&")
=>"asdf \\& asdf"
```

Yes, if I puts the string it will return what I want:

```
>>puts "asdf & asdf".gsub("&", "\\\\&")
=>asdf \& asdf
```

But I need the actual string to equal `asdf \& asdf`

I've tried inspect:

```
>>"asdf & asdf".gsub("&", "\\\\&").inspect
=>"\"asdf \\\\& asdf\""

>>"asdf & asdf".gsub("&", "\&").inspect
=>"\"asdf & asdf\""
```

But that also does not return what I need. Maybe there is some combination that I'm missing that will return a \& in the string?

Thanks

Comment: Try this: `str = "asdf \\& asdf"; str.chars #=> ["a", "s", "d", "f", " ", "\\", "&", " ", "a", "s", "d", "f"]; str.size #=> 12; str.each_char.map(&:ord) #=> [97, 115, 100, 102, 32, 92, 38, 32, 97, 115, 100, 102]`. We see that `"\\".ord #=> 92`. 
Upon consulting any [ASCII table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) we see the character with ASCII value 92 is a backslash. Were we to write `"\".size` Ruby would wait patiently for the closing double-quote. So far the string contains a single character, an escaped double-quote, which is just a double-quote.

Comment: Seems the OP is confused between the internally-held String and what is output to the terminal you see (or hear if you are using auditorial terminal). The comment by @CarySwoveland is good. A short-form is `"asdf \\& asdf".codepoints`

Comment: Correction to my comment above: So far, the string contains an escaped double-quote (which is just a double-quote) followed by the five characters `.size`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you see Ruby showing something like:

```
"asdf \\& asdf"
```

That's broken up into the tokens `\\` (backslash) and `&` (ampersand) where the first backslash is special, the second is an actual character. You can read this as "*literal* backslash".

When printed you're seeing the actual string. It's correct.

Internally the double backslashes aren't actually there, it's just a consequence of how double-quoted strings must be handled.

This is to ensure that `\n` and `\r` and other control characters work, but you're also able to put in actual backslashes. There's a big difference between `\n` (newline) and `\\n` (*literal* backslash letter n).

You'll see this often when dealing with data formats that have special characters. For example, in `printf` style formatters `%` is significant, so to print an actual `%` you need to double it up:

```
'%.1f%%' % 10.3
#=> "10.3%"
```

Each format will have its own quirks and concerns. HTML doesn't treat backslash as special, but it does `<` and `>` and `&`, so you'll see `&amp;` instead of ampersand.

Comment: Good answer. Another way of saying this is that `"\\"` represents a single backslash although you see two. Just like `"\n"` represents a newline although you don't see the newline char.