# Non-regexp version of gsub in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, replace, gsub

I am looking for a version of `gsub` which doesn't try to interpret its input as regular expressions and uses normal C-like escaped strings.

**Update**

The question was initiated by a strange behavior:

```
text.gsub("pattern", "\\\\\\")
```

and

```
text.gsub("pattern", "\\\\\\\\")
```

are treated as the same, and

```
text.gsub("pattern", "\\\\")
```

is treated as single backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two layers of escaping for the second parameter of gsub:

The first layer is Ruby string constant. If it is written like `\\\\\\` it is unescaped by Ruby like `\\\`

the second layer is gsub itself: `\\\` is treated like `\\` + `\`

double backslash is resolved into single: `\\` => `\` and the single trailing backslash at the end is resolved as itself.

8 backslashes are parsed in the similar way:

```
"\\\\\\\\" => "\\\\"
```

and then

```
"\\\\" => "\\"
```

so the constants consisting of six and eight backslashes are resolved into two backslashes.

To make life a bit easier, a block may be used in gsub function. String constants in a block are passed only through Ruby layer (thanks to @Sorrow).

```
"foo\\bar".gsub("\\") {"\\\\"}
```

Answer (score 2):

`gsub` accepts strings as first parameter:

```
the pattern is typically a Regexp; if given as
a String, any regular expression metacharacters
it contains will be interpreted literally
```

Example:

```
"hello world, i am thy code".gsub("o", "-foo-")
=> "hell-foo- w-foo-rld, i am thy c-foo-de"
```

Comment: Then why to replace to two backslashes \\ I have to write SIX backslashes? "\\\\\\" See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542214/weird-backslash-substitution-in-ruby

Comment: not quite sure what you mean... `"foo\\\\bar".gsub("\\\\", "-")` results in `"foo-bar"` (also `"foo\\\\bar".count('\\') == 2`) as long as you operate on strings, that is... if you do it the other way around (replace something with two \s) - the answer is in the thread you linked (gruesome details ;); for that reason (and for other clarity reasons) I would recommend you to use block syntax of `gsub` instead of two parameters

Comment: Try to replace single backslash to double backslash and you'll see.

Comment: yup, it does not work when you use two arguments for gsub, but it works when you use a block call: `"foo\\bar".gsub("\\") {"\\\\"}`