# How come you can't gsub this string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

These `\\n` are showing up in my strings even though it should only be `\n`.

But if I do this :

```
"\n".gsub('\\n','\b')
```

It returns :

```
"\n"
```

Ideally, I'm trying to find a regex that could rewrite this string :

```
"R3pQvDqmz/EQ7zho2mhIeE6UB4dLa6GUH7173VEMdGCcdsRm5pernkqCgbnj\\nZjTX\\n"
```

To not display two backslashes, but just one like this :

```
"R3pQvDqmz/EQ7zho2mhIeE6UB4dLa6GUH7173VEMdGCcdsRm5pernkqCgbnj\nZjTX\n"
```

But any of the regex I do will not work. I can gsub out the `\n` and put something like `X` there, but if I put a `\` in it, then Ruby escapes it with an additional `\` which consequentially destroys my encryption module as it needs to be specific.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what your actual goal is, but try `'\n'` instead of `"\n"`

Comment: Replace `\\n` with the string `\n`, or the *character* newline?

Comment: Here's a related topic about blackslashes in gsub: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542214/weird-backslash-substitution-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are falling into the trap of a different meaning of escapes when used in strings with double quotes vs single quotes. Double-quoted strings allow escape characters to be used. Thus, here `"\n"` actually is a one-character string containing a single line feed. Compare that to `'\n'` which is a two-character string containing a literal backslash followed by a character n.

This explains, whey your `gsub` doesn't match. If you use the following code, it should work:

```
"\\n".gsub('\n','\b')
```

For your actual issue, you can use this

```
string = "R3pQvDqmz/EQ7zho2mhIeE6UB4dLa6GUH7173VEMdGCcdsRm5pernkqCgbnj\\nZjTX\\n"
new_string = string.gsub("\\n", "\n")
```

Comment: +1 To further clarify the first case: `"\n".gsub("\n",'\b')` results in `"\\b"`.

Comment: It was a bit unclear what Trip actually wanted to achieve with his first example. The code I used matches his data so I chose this. Your example works too. The point is, he tried to match different things and thus didn't get the result he expected.