# Gsub causing part of string to be substituted

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I want to replace all occurrences of a single quote (`'`) with backslash single quote (`\'`). I tried doing this with `gsub`, but I'm getting partial string duplication:

```
a = "abc 'def' ghi"
a.gsub("'", "\\'")
# => "abc def' ghidef ghi ghi"
```

Can someone explain why this happens and what a solution to this is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542214/weird-backslash-substitution-in-ruby should answer your question

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply bjhaid! That answers my question. You should have posted it as answer. Then I could've upvoted you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because `"\\'"` has a special meaning when it occurs as the replacement argument of `gsub`, namely it means the post-match substring.

To do what you want, you can use a block:

```
a.gsub("'"){"\\'"}
# => "abc \\'def\\' ghi"
```

Notice that the backslash is escaped in the string inspection, so it appears as `\\`.

Comment: You don't need to use the block form; you just need to prepend ``\'`` with another ``\``, which in double-quotes looks like `"\\\\'"`: `a.gsub("'", "\\\\'")`

Answer (score 3):

Your `"\\'"` actually represents a literal `\'` because of the backslash escaping the next backslash. And that literal `\'` in Ruby regex is actually a special variable that interpolates to *the part of the string that follows the matched portion*. So here's what's happening.

```
abc 'def' ghi
    ^
```

The caret points to the first match, `'`. Replace it with everything to its right, *i.e.* `def' ghi`.

```
abc def' ghidef' ghi
    ++++++++
```

Now find the next match:

```
abc def' ghidef' ghi
               ^
```

Once again, replace the `'` with everything to its right, *i.e.*  `ghi`.

```
abc def' ghidef ghi ghi
               ++++
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate explanation!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible you just need a higher dose of escaping:

```
a.gsub(/'/, "\\\\'" )
```

**Result**:

> abc \'def\' ghi

Comment: This is same as a.gsub("'", "\\\\'")