# backslash at end of string causes error when inserting into InfluxDB

Tags: ruby, escaping, influxdb

I have a string:

```
string = "\\"
puts string
# => \
```

I am interpolating this into a new string and sending to a database. However the database (InfluxDB) uses backslashes as escape characters so pushing this string can cause an error.

For example, if I pass the following to Influx it will cause an "unterminated string" error:

```
insert_cmd = <<-TXT
  INSERT INTO my_db.default.my_measurement,my_tag=1 my_val="#{string}"
TXT
```

My question is how can I replace `\` in a string with `\\` (two actual backslashes).

I have it working with `gsub("\\", "\\\\\\")` but I don't understand why this works and the following doesn't:

```
string.gsub("\\", "\\\\")
# SyntaxError: (irb):10: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting end-of-input
```

Why doesn't this work? Why does `gsub("\\", "\\\\\\")` work? Is there a better way?

---

**solved**

As I mentioned in a comment, actually I am not manually interpolating into a INSERT INTO string. I am using influxdb-ruby:

```
INFLUXDB_CLIENT.write_point("things", time: Time.now.to_i, values: { foo: "\\" })
```

It turns out this is a bug with that gem: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-ruby/issues/200

It is fixed in v 0.4.2 and i was using 0.4.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird backslash substitution in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542214/weird-backslash-substitution-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use parameterized query strings:

```
INSERT INTO my_db.default.my_measurement,my_tag=1 my_val=%{1}
```

Where when you call it you do this:

```
influxdb.query("...query...", params: [ string ])
```

What you did was create a classic [injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) by sending unescaped data into a query. The same principle applies in any database with a plain-text string representation, or even other data formats like HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-ruby which I assumed sanitized everything, I guess not. I have commetned on their Github and awaiting response.

Comment: They can only sanitize *if* you use the parameterized query feature. There's no other way for them to know what you're putting in your string. The way you avoid injection bugs is by not injecting in the first place.

Comment: I guess my question was a little misleading. Actually what I'm doing is calling `INFLUXDB_CLIENT.write_point("things", time: Time.now.to_i, values: { foo: "\\" })`. So I'm not really interpolating myself, it's done by the gem.

Comment: Yeah, that is a little misleading since that's completely different from the code in your question.

Comment: the insert snippet was a little tangential, i was meaning to focus more on the `gsub` code which is addressed by the answer marked as duplicate. However I accepted yours because it ended up being more apt for my situation. I guess it's a bit of an X/Y problem.

Comment: It turns out I didn't find the bug, but it was a bug. See https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-ruby/issues/200 I was using version 0.4.1 and the bug was fixed in 0.4.2