# How to replace & with \& with gsub on rails?

Tags: regex, ruby, string

I'm writting a ruby-on-rails application that fills latex formulars. Now I run into an pdflatex error when a user filed variable includes the character `&` (e.g., Company & Co. KG). For latex it is a new table column and I need to escape these characters with `\&`.

I'm using `Rails 5.2.3` with `ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]` on `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS`.

I've tried using `gsub` to replace all `&` in a string but ran into two problems.

1. `\&` is replaced by the matched string
2. I can only insert a double backslash `\\`

So I also tried replace the character before a `&` with a `\` with no success.

```rb
a = "T & T"
a.gsub(&, "\&")               -> "T & T"
a.gsub(/(.{1})(?=&)/, " \")   -> error:  unterminated string meets end of file
a.gsub(/(.{1})(?=&)/, " \\")  -> "T \\& T"
```

How can I replace a character with a single `\` or can I escape the reversed `\&` somehow?

Comment: You are most likely inspecting your string in a way that shows you the escaped version. Try this in irb: `92.chr` (which produces a string with a single slash) will output `"\\"`; but `puts 92.chr` will produce `\ `, the true content of the string. None of your code is giving you double backslashes.

Comment: Do you want to replace "&" and " " both ? or just "&" with space?

Comment: What if your `&`  is already escaped? You will have two backslashes before the `&` if you use `.gsub('&', '\\\&')`. Use `.gsub(/\\?&/, '\\\&')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use triple `\` in the replacement string:

```
print 'Company & Co. KG'.gsub('&', '\\\&')
# Company \& Co. KG=> nil
```

You can check that a single backslash is added by checking the length of both strings:

```
'Company & Co. KG'.size
# => 16
'Company & Co. KG'.gsub('&', '\\\&').size
# => 17
```

To understand it better, read about escaping:

- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Single_quotes
- https://gist.github.com/kbaribeau/1103102
- [Weird backslash substitution in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542214/weird-backslash-substitution-in-ruby)

EDIT:

`\&` is a [backreference to the whole match](https://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/60-escape-back-referencing.html) (like `\0`)

```
'Company & Co. KG'.gsub(/Co/, '-\&-')
# => "-Co-mpany & -Co-. KG"
'Company & Co. KG'.gsub(/Co/, '-\0-')
# => "-Co-mpany & -Co-. KG"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working. When I run this I get ```>> 'Company & Co. KG'.gsub('&', '\\\&') => "Company \\& Co. KG"```

Comment: Read my comment under the question. There are _not_ two backslashes in the result, despite the appearances. This answer is correct.

Comment: Is there a way to esacpe the `\&` ? I ran into further problems because the actual filling of my tex file is done again by gsub which reads the `\&` as `\0` as you stated. Edit: The solutions in your link don't work for me